# What is the best approach / database to store a large array of strings (range of 2 Million)?

Tags: database, mongodb

The array of strings has frequent updates (addition of new values & removal of existing values). It  has to be highly available for read too. Currently I am using mongoDb for this which is starting to slow down (10sec+ on updates). I need a alternate approach or a better database for this functionality.

I tried adding indexes & upgrading instances which didnt help in solving the issue.

Comment: I don't think 2 million strings in an array per row or document, would work in any database.